# Automatically resize JPanel without use BorderLayout.CENTER

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jdesktoppane

I have a `JPanel` inside a `JDesktopPane` and I need to resize the panel automatically when the size of desktopPane changes.

The size of panel always needs to be the same of `desktopPane`. I can't use `BorderLayout.CENTER` because if I use it, I cant resize others frames inside of `desktopPane`.

Thanks

Comment: The panel should span the entire desktopPane and yet there are other frames? I'd say you need to clarify what exactly you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I Have a desktopPane and I need to put a JPanel inside. The JPanel need always to be the same size of desktopPane. And inside the desktopPane I can open other frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ComponentListener/Adapter

```
JDesktopPane desktop = ...;
JPanel p = ...;

ComponentListener cl = new ComponentAdapter() {
  public void componentResized(ComponentEvent ce) {
    //reset your panel size here
  }
}

desktop.addComponentListener(cl);
```

Comment: Do you know some listener to know when color of desktopPane was changed? Like this listener to know when the size was changed?

Comment: You should try PropertyChangeListener... It may or may not work. If it doesn't, you can subclass JDesktopPane and override its setColor method to work either with a PropertyChangeListener or with your own custom listener